# Looking for a Rails plugin for modular wiki functionality

Tags: ruby-on-rails, wiki, ruby-on-rails-plugins

There are a few plugins that implement a traditional wiki (collection of stand-alone wiki pages in a flat namespace), including irwi and wiki_column.  That's not what I want.

What I want is something modular, so I can add a wiki panel on any random page of my website, or have fields in several different models be "wikified" (editable by all with version history).  In other words, I want embeddable wiki objects rather than a full-page wiki, and I want the wiki content blocks to be anonymous rather than named in a unified flat namespace, or associable with specific objects.

Is there anything like that?

Comment: did you ever find anything to do this, or did you have to build this from scratch? thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To wikify content is rather easy, so here some thoughts to it:

- Have a look at the [Railscast: Markdown with Redcarpet](http://railscasts.com/episodes/272-markdown-with-redcarpet) which explains how to wikify (that means style) content as HTML. That is one of the things you have to have to wikify pages. It is rather simple, and works like a charm.
- Second, how will you link to "wiki content" without a name? For me, wiki is at least some content that is linked ...
- To get a history, you should link your model object to versions of model. The [Railscast #177](http://railscasts.com/episodes/177-model-versioning?view=asciicast) implements a wiki with versioning, perhaps that gives you enough hints to do it.

To add "a wiki panel" means then, that you have a (versioned) model `WikiPanel`, that may then used by other models. Hope my hints give you a starting point (even if it comes 20 months too late ...).

Comment: Thanks!  I knew all that already, but it is still a good answer.

I didn't find what I want, so I will be implementing my own solution, possibly with some tricky bits (like generating colored diffs) stolen from out Rails wikis.  I'll finally be getting around to it in the next few weeks.  :)

Answer (score 0):

You could check out AdvaCMS, which features a wiki. AdvaCMS is built with Rails Engines (e.g. plugins). Check it out at http://adva-cms.org/wiki

Comment: Interesting, but I don't think that's what I'm looking for, and the docs are spotty.  Since irwi is tiny, I'm thinking of maybe just reading through the code and modifying it be embeddable in the manner I need, so I can at least inherit the version history/diff/compare functionality.